# Two ValidationSummary controls in asp.net displaying with an extra line in between the errors

Tags: asp.net, css, validationsummary

I have two ValidationSummary controls on one page:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ForeColor="Red" Style="margin-left: 1.5%" ID="ValidationSummary"     
    runat="server"/> 
<asp:ValidationSummary ForeColor="Red" Style="margin-left: 1.5%" runat="server"     
    ValidationGroup="vgOnScreen"  />
```

These are both triggered by one button. Now my problem is, when there in an error for each control, it is displayed with an extra line in between which is inconsistent with the look of the application.

This is what the display looks like:

```
    •This is my first error

    •This is my second error
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of the extra line between two validation summary controls?

Comment: Because I am referring to the asp.net validation summary. @walther I know css and it isnt helping

Comment: And what does have validation summary to do with C# and VB.NET? Also, you should show the css...

Comment: @walther I will appreciate limiting your questions to the onus of my question: How do I get rid of that extra line? thanks

Comment: If you look at the generated HTML and use css you supposedly know, it's a task for 10-30 seconds to figure this out.